# How to get the document.title of a website opened via window.open (ssl secured)

Tags: javascript, ssl, google-oauth, same-origin-policy

Trying to get the `document.title` of a third party website (using ssl) opened via `window.open()`, always results in a cross origin error:

> Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'

I'm trying to get the window title of a third party website (Google) from my web application. The main problem is, that the application can run from any host/domain (in multiple installations), so I cannot configure a correct "referer" in the Google Developers Console. There are thousands of domains and hosts.

This is my code:

```js
var wnd = window.open('https://google.com', 'myPopup', 'width=800,height=600');

window.setInterval(
  function() {
    console.log(wnd.document.title);
  }, 1000
);
```

Also available as a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SuperNova3000/yw7mcc3y/

Is there any way to get the window title? I really don't need to get access to the rest of the document. May be there is a hidden (browser specific) feature? I cannot manipulate the target website before. **The main goal is to get the Google Success Code for OAuth 2.0 without copy paste.**

Before asking the question I already read the following document: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp - But this does not really cover the situation, that the "application" is a web-application that's used like a native installed application.

Comment: No, that is not possible with JavaScript executed in the scope of a website – the Same Origin Policy is in place to prevent that.

Comment: _“The main goal is to get the Google Success Code for OAuth 2.0 without copy paste”_ – well, then implement the OAuth flow properly.

Comment: It sounds like each installation of your application should have it's own OAuth 2.0 client credentials configured, on a Google account that belongs to the site admin.

Comment: @CBroe: Don't know what you'd like to tell me. Yes same origin policy is in place.

Comment: @William Denniss: There is no way to get the google site admin keep in sync with thousand of installations. Each is getting it's own domain. Our application i always the same. However, the main question is: Is there any way to get the window title of an ssl site via JavaScript?

Comment: This has nothing to do with SSL – it has to do with the content loaded into your popup being from a different domain, which means you do not have access to it via scripting. // If you need to use one and the same app across “thousands” of domains (which OAuth implementations by f.e. Google and Facebook are in general _not_ supposed to support actually), then your only workaround is to use one dedicated domain for login purposes, link/redirect the user there, handle the response “on” that domain, and redirect the user back to whatever domain your app is actually used on in this instance.

Comment: It sounds strange. But when developing an native application for example windows, you may also have thousands of installation. The difference is, that you can embed a browser windows and read the title. So Google the "leader" of webapplication is not able to support this? The only little thing that has to be done is reading the TITLE of the document, nothing else. May be there is a browser workaround for this?